# R - How to filter based on all rows (too many to write out)?

Tags: r

I have a data.table that I am trying to filter. Basically, for any row that has a value of "--" (they are all characters, and that was put in place of NA) in any one of about 750 columns, I want to delete that row.

Here is a sample dataset:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)

snp <- c(1:5)
id1 <- c("AA", "AB", "BB", "--", "AA")
id2 <- c(rep("AA", 5))
id3 <- c("BB", "AB", "--", "AA", "AA")

data1 <- as.data.table(cbind(snp, id1, id2, id3))
data1
```

I also have a version of this dataset that is transposed, so I could filter out any column that has "--" in it, but I figured filtering rows would be easier.

Since there are hundreds of columns with strange names, I can't write out a function that includes each one with & between each one, such as:

```
data2 <- data1 %>% 
  filter(id1 != "--" & id2 != "--" & id3 != "--")
data2
```

How can I filter based on every column at once with so many columns?

Thank you!

P.S. I know this sounds easy, but I have been searching for an answer for awhile and have come up dry.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `if_all`

```
library(dplyr)
data1 %>% 
   filter(if_all(starts_with('id'), ~ .x != '--'))
     snp    id1    id2    id3
   <int> <char> <char> <char>
1:     1     AA     AA     BB
2:     2     AB     AA     AB
3:     5     AA     AA     AA
```

---

Or with `if_any` and negate (`!`)

```
data1 %>% 
  filter(!if_any(starts_with('id'), ~ .x == '--'))
     snp    id1    id2    id3
   <int> <char> <char> <char>
1:     1     AA     AA     BB
2:     2     AB     AA     AB
3:     5     AA     AA     AA
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks promising. One more detail that is getting in the way is that not all of the columns start with the same character (they actually start with different numbers). Is there a way to include that in the code? I've tried a couple things, but I haven't gotten it to work yet. Thanks again!

Comment: instead of `starts_with('id')` use `everything()`

Comment: @AndS. Thank you! I also was able to use matches("[0123456789]")

Comment: @AndS. If you want to match other than 'snp', use `if_all(-snp,`

Answer (score 0):

Many use the tidyverse as their default data wrangling tool set.  For me base R is sometimes clearer and more compact.  Here is a base R solution using a toy example.  The `z` and `df2` lines are all that are required.

```
set.seed(7)
s <- sample(c(LETTERS, "--"), 120, replace = TRUE)
m <- matrix(s, ncol = 10)
df <- data.frame(m)
df
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   J  V  P  X  I  X  U  X  M   I
2   S  O  V  K  U  J  I  G  L   Z
3   G  H --  H  V  N  P  Y  W   Q
4   B --  U  Q  H  Z  W  Y  W   H
5   O  Z  D --  M  H  H  X  R   I
6   Z  L  K  N  O --  P  V  A  --
7   V  S  F  D  I  P  R  L  Q   I
8   H  T  Z  Y  B  R  R  F  A   V
9   X  H  W  C  L  W  H  D  L   T
10  C  R  B  M  U  E  F  P  K   N
11  X  O  D  U  H  F  J  Q  P   K
12  H  F  F  X  Z  C  M  K  B   X
z <- apply(df, 1, function(x) all(x != "--"))
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
df2 <- df[which(z), ]
df2
   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
1   J  V  P  X  I  X  U  X  M   I
2   S  O  V  K  U  J  I  G  L   Z
7   V  S  F  D  I  P  R  L  Q   I
8   H  T  Z  Y  B  R  R  F  A   V
9   X  H  W  C  L  W  H  D  L   T
10  C  R  B  M  U  E  F  P  K   N
11  X  O  D  U  H  F  J  Q  P   K
12  H  F  F  X  Z  C  M  K  B   X
```